# How do you make a popup overflow a scrolling div?

Tags: css

I have a scrolling DIV, which contains a list of many items:

```
 ___________
|         |^|
| Item1   | |
|_________| |
|         | |
| Item2   | |
|_________| |
|         | |
| Item3   | |
|_________|v|
```

When the user rolls over a list item, a popup appears describing that item:

```
 ___________
|         |^|
| Item1   | |
|_________| |
|        _|_|____________________
| Item2 | Description for item 2 |
|________------------------------
|         | |
| Item3   | |
|_________|v|
```

The dilemma is the scrolling div must have overflow:auto, but the popup wants to be visible outside of the div. So currently, my popup gets chopped off:

```
 ___________
|         |^|
| Item1   | |
|_________| |
|        _|_|
| Item2 | De|
|________---|
|         | |
| Item3   | |
|_________|v|
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="box">
  <ul>
    <li>
       <h2>Item 1</h2>
       <span>Description for item 1</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <h2>Item 2</h2>
       <span>Description for item 2</span>
    </li>
    <!-- ... and many other items --->
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box {
   width: 10em;
   height: 20em;
   overflow: auto;
}

#box ul {
   line-height: 2em;
}

#box ul li {
   position: relative;
}

#box ul li span {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   right: -1em;
   top: 1em;
   height: 1em;
}

#box ul li:hover span {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try experimenting with position:fixed on the popup element and see if that helps you:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpEb2/

Comment: A fixed positioned element's origin is the upper left of the body. I wanted the popup to be positioned relative to the list item, not the body.

Comment: if you scroll the element the popup position will be the same

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you do something else to work around this. If you use JavaScript, you can make a module specifically for the popup box. So whenever you want to have popup in your current page, you just include that module.

You can make that module html and JavaScript mixed, with a hidden popup div with absolute position. Whenever you move the cursor over some element on your page with tooltips enabled, just call a JavaScript function to bring that hidden popup over at where the cursor (or the element) is and show the popup with proper info.

This implementation can make your popup system very modular and adaptable, you can have a uniformed popup in your whole website, and you can modify its properties very easily.